# c# set main window after startup window

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

If I start my application I start one custom window with 3 button's. Here is the `app.xaml` Code:

```
<Application x:Class="EbayManager.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Startup="ApplicationStart">
</Application>
```

Here is the `app.xaml.cs` Code:

```
    private void ApplicationStart(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

        ChooseAccountWindow chooseAccountWindow = new ChooseAccountWindow();
        chooseAccountWindow.ShowDialog();

        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(chooseAccountWindow.Result);
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
```

The `ChooseAccountWindow` have 3 button's here is the `CustomAccountWindow.xaml.cs` Code:

```
public partial class ChooseAccountWindow : MetroWindow
{

    public string Result { get; set; }

    public ChooseAccountWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnDastaschentuch2013_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Result = "dastaschentuch2013";
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnSkeptar_de_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Result = "skeptar_de";
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnAsdf_de_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Result = "asdf_de";
        this.Close();
    }


}
```

The `ChooseAccountWindow.xaml` should be an second window, and the main window should be the `MainWindow.xaml`. After pressing a button I want, that the second window `ChooseAccountWindow.xaml` will closed & the main window should be displayed. Is that the correct way? Because this two commands:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(chooseAccountWindow.Result);
mainWindow.Show();
```

open the main window, but the title isn't displayed and I cant set the height & width of the window.

Here is the `MainWindow.xaml` Code:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="EbayManager.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="3500" Width="525" GlowBrush="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}">
<Grid>
</Grid>
```

Here is the Code of the `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
namespace EbayManager
{
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    private string p;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainWindow(string p)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.p = p;
        MessageBox.Show(p);
    }
}
```

}

Maybe someone of you can help me.

Comment: I'm not seeing code where you are setting the title, height, or width. It's also ambiguous regarding which window you are trying to set this one.

Comment: @CoryCharlton sorry, edited the post.

Comment: That all looks good. What are you doing in the `MainWindow` constructor? Are you setting `ShowTitleBar = false` or changing the `WindowStyle`?

Comment: @CoryCharlton nope, I edited my Question again and added the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` Code

Comment: I create with the 2 command's `MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(chooseAccountWindow.Result);
mainWindow.Show();`, a new Window, but not a new Window of the class *MainWindow.xaml*, because if I ad a button nothing happens.

Comment: @CoryCharlton Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `MainWindow(string p)` constructor is not calling `InitializeComponent()`. Change to this:

```
public MainWindow(string p): this()
{
    // TODO: Complete member initialization
    this.p = p;
    MessageBox.Show(p);
}
```

Or this:

```
public MainWindow(string p)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // TODO: Complete member initialization
    this.p = p;
    MessageBox.Show(p);
}
```

**Edit:**

Here's an example that shows what happens when you specify `this()` on the `MainWindow(string p)` constructor:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t2 = new Test2("blah");
    }
}

class Test1
{
    public Test1()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("I'm in Test1.ctor()");
    }
}

class Test2: Test1
{
    public Test2()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("I'm in Test2.ctor()");

        Initialize();
    }

    public Test2(string blah) : this()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("I'm in Test2.ctor(string blah)");
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("I'm in Test2.Initialize()");

    }
}
```

The output is:

```
I'm in Test1.ctor() // Base constructors called first
I'm in Test2.ctor() // Specified constructor `this()` called
I'm in Test2.Initialize() // This is in the `Test2()` constructor so it executes
I'm in Test2.ctor(string blah) // Finally the code in `Test2(string blah)` is executed
```

Comment: wow thanks, it works! :) I have one question: **With `:this()`, the code excecute the `public MainWindow()` method?**.

Comment: Correct. I'll add a simple example to explain what's going on.

Comment: Added the example. Without specifying the `this()` constructor the compiler will call `base()` which doesn't have your `InitializeComponent()` code

Answer (score 1):

Your comment that the title isn't displayed and you can't set the height and width of the window tell me that the problem has nothing to do with what you have put in your original post.  The problem is most likely linked to the WindowStyle of MainWindow, or other properties relating to MainWindow.